# How to get focus to IE8 window ? SetForegroundWindow()?

Tags: c++, winapi, setfocus, lostfocus

I am using the following line

```
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
```

in c++ to get focus to an ie8 window. What actually happens is , i get focus for 2 times and after that if i open the next time instead of getting the focus, it just blinks in the  taskbar in orange colour. 
Please provide me a resolution for this. 
Any alternative for `SetForegroundWindow()`?
I have tried using

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SW_SHOW,0);
```

It did not work.

Comment: This thread seems to cover it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772233/win32-setforegroundwindow-unreliable

Comment: The documentation for [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) explains under which conditions this API call can be used. This answers one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```