# Put application to foreground

Tags: windows, c++11, process, foreground

I have to put a window to foreground using its name, for example "images".
With

```
findWindowW(NULL, stringName)
```

I get the handle to the process (`HWND`).
Then with

```
SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
```

I think that I put it into the foreground automatically, but I have to press 'Enter'. Am I doing something wrong or there's another way to do that? I can use also the PID of the process. 

My final purpose is to send shortcuts like CTRL+V to the process after put it into  the foreground. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The process is being debugged.
> - The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - No menus are active.

So, if your program does not correspond to the above,  you can not set foreground automatically.

I think you can use below code for your case and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772233/win32-setforegroundwindow-unreliable) can be help as well.

```
void SetForegroundWindowForce(HWND hWnd)
{
   HWND hWndForeground = ::GetForegroundWindow();
   if(hWndForeground == hWnd) return;

   DWORD Strange = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWndForeground, NULL);
   DWORD My = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL);
   if( !::AttachThreadInput(My, Strange, TRUE) )
   {
      ASSERT(0);
   }
   ::SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
   ::BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
   if( !::AttachThreadInput(My, Strange, FALSE) )
   {
      ASSERT(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't try it, but looking at MSDN I think I've understood. Here's my interpretation: first keep the handle to the foreground window and the corrent window; then with AttachThreadInput() the process share the input buffer (not so sure about that...) than I set the other window on top and "split" the two process. <br>I'm not so sure about that, if something is completely wrong please point out it to me, thank you!!

Comment: You're almost correct. By using `AttachThreadInput`, two different thread can share their input states such  as keyboard, mouse, etc. Your window handle can acquire **right condition** as calling `AttatchThreadInput` function with specifying **TRUE** for second parameter.

Comment: Ok. I run that method with the handle of the window. AttachThreadInput returns a value greater than 0 so it does what is in the if ( I don't know how assert works with only a parameter..). 
What if I want to send a combination of keys to the second window? Even without change the focus.