# Set the Active/Focused Window in Windows WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, user32

I have a WPF C# desktop application that's installed on Windows 10 PC's. The app is used by customers at the front desk reception, where they complete a specific set of tasks. In the last step the app launches a URL using the 'default' Web browser so they can complete the final step. This last step has to be done on the Web.

Once the customer completes the final task in the browser Window (usually takes about 15 seconds), I need the Windows app to once again become the active/focused Window. Otherwise, when the next customer comes to the counter, they see the browser window. But they need to see the WPF app.

In my code I create a **DispatcherTimer** with a 30 second timer that gets started just before the app launches the URL:

```
DispatcherTimer focus_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
focus_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
focus_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(focus_timer_Tick);
```

Code in the timer tick event:

```
focus_timer.Stop();
this.Activate();
this.Focus();
```

The above code had no effect - Chrome still sits in the foreground over the top of the WPF Windows app. I then tried using the **SetForegroundWindow** function from the **user32.dll** with the following unmanaged code:

```
// code in the Window class
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// code in the timer tick event
focus_timer.Stop();
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
bool is_ok = SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
```

This also didn't work. The above code simply causes the WPF app's icon on the Windows Taskbar to pulse, and again Chrome stays on top. I also tried the following code:

```
// code in the Window class
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// code in the timer tick event
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
IntPtr ptrActive = SetActiveWindow(windowHandle);
IntPtr ptrFocus = SetFocus(windowHandle);
```

The above code also doesn't appear to do anything.

ptrActive returns: 0x00000000

ptrFocus returns: 0x0004086a

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772233/win32-setforegroundwindow-unreliable

Comment: Basically Windows let's you use SetForegroundWindow under certain conditions, so that you won't disturb the user. In some cases this can be circumvented by temporarily attaching the thread input queue to the current foreground window's.